# Display string with misencoded characters as "?" C#

Tags: c#, memory, encoding, char, byte

I am currently working on an assignment where they asked me to recreate the memory viewer in visualstudio as a standalone program.

The issue I have been running into is the fact that Visual Studio uses some kind of non standard encoding with the extended ascii characterset (which is not in the standard Encoding class in C#).

If I print the string in the console some characters are represented as "?". This is fine and is considered a nonissue, the problem is that whenever I put sxaid string into the listbox for display, it filters out any "?" and just straight up removes them. Is there any way I can somehow make sure that either it displays a "?" or that I can fix the encoding?

Here are some screenshots from VS and my program as well as the console output

VS

[image: Visual Studio]

My program

[image: My program]

Console Output

[image: Console Output]

EDIT: Woops I forgot to post the code...

```
        public unsafe void FillForm(IntPtr startAddress)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        listBox3.Items.Clear();

        ReadMemory read = new ReadMemory();

        List<MemoryModel> memoryModels = new List<MemoryModel>();

        byte[] mem = read.ReadAddress(startAddress, DisplaySize);
        char[] memChars = new char[mem.Length];

        //dataGridView1.Columns.Add("0", "Address");
        for (int i = 0; i < DisplaySize; i++)
        {
            //dataGridView2.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
            //dataGridView3.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < DisplaySize; i++)
        {
            //listBox2.Items.Add();
            //dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
            listBox1.Items.Add("0x" + (startAddress + DisplaySize * i).ToString("X8"));
            //dataGridView1[0, i].Value = 

            MemoryModel model = new MemoryModel();


            for (int j = 0; j < DisplaySize; j++)
            {
                //memChars[j] = mem[j] == 255 || mem[j] == 127 || mem[j] < 33 ? '.' : (char)mem[j];
                memChars[j] = mem[j] == 255 || mem[j] == 127 || mem[j] < 33 || ((char)mem[j]).ToString().Contains("\\u")? '.' : (char)mem[j];

                Console.WriteLine(memChars[j] + " + " + mem[j]);
                model.ByteStringAccordingToSize += mem[j].ToString("X2") + " ";
            }


            //convert to model
            model.CharRepresentation = new string(memChars);


            model.FirstByteAddress = "0x" + (startAddress + DisplaySize * i).ToString("X10");

            Console.WriteLine("============ \n ROW: " + i);
            Console.WriteLine(model.CharRepresentation);
            Console.WriteLine("============");

            memoryModels.Add(model);

            mem = read.ReadAddress(startAddress + DisplaySize * (i + 1), DisplaySize);
        }

        foreach (var memoryModel in memoryModels)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(memoryModel.ByteStringAccordingToSize);
            listBox3.Items.Add(memoryModel.CharRepresentation);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't show the part of your software which output that.

Comment: wheres the code?

Comment: I am so sorry! I fixed it